# How to print the result from function (my extension of Codingbat question : Warmup-1 > near_hundred)

Tags: python

I would just like to mention that i am very new to coding, i've begun with learning Python.
After completing a codingbat question I was trying to print the result (as per below), however it wasn't working for me. I would greatly appreciate if someone can please provide any help.

I understand that my solution can be written more simply however I'm still learning and the following made sense for me (and seeemed to work as well). I have tried some variations of the below however couldn't quite get it to work. I tried to have something like `def near_hundred(input(n))` however that didn't really work. Also tried having print(near_hundred) at the bottom of the code and was unsuccessful.

```
n = input('Please enter number: ')
def near_hundred(n):
    if n in range (90,110) or n in range (190,211):
        return True
        print('this number is within range')
    else:
        return False
        print('this number is out of range')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your function. The function will do nothing until you use it

```
n = int(input('Please enter number: '))
def near_hundred(n):
    if n in range (90,110) or n in range (190,211):
        print('this number is within range')
    else:
        print('this number is out of range')

near_hundred(n)
```

Comment: This doesn't work since you're not entering the number argument

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
n = input('Please enter number: ')
def near_hundred(n):
    if n in range (90,110) or n in range (190,211):
        print('this number is within range')
    else:
        print('this number is out of range')
print(near_hundred(n))
```

Comment: this is returning **true** or **false** value but not printing anything

Comment: @MohitChandel It does print something!

Comment: Thank you for your help, this did work however I was wanting to print the specific lines rather than either True or False.

Comment: @Blender Edited mine